# Cesium How to draw Polyline using Path positions

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, cesiumjs

I'm using `Cesium.SampledPositionProperty()` to draw and **interpolate path** as given in  [[Reference1]](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=Interpolation.html). I'm achieving to draw a Polyline instead of Path for some reasons. To do that I have added a Polyine object inside the entity, and giving it's positions like:

```
polyline: {
    positions: position._property._values,
    width: 10,
    material: Cesium.Color.GREEN
}
```

But not getting success. I want to apply Path's interpolation to the polyline also.
Please check the complete effort on Sandcastle [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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)

Comment: The correct way to do this is with PathGraphics, not a Polyline.  Check out lines 92 to 98 of the [Interpolation Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Interpolation.html).